# json.loads() doesn't pull in complete python file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm running the following code, trying to pull in the data in `file.json` to work as a dictionary in python.

```
with open('file.json') as data:
    my_data = json.loads(data.read())
```

And when I call `my_data`, the file is incomplete. It starts after 67792 lines or 1799045 characters. The full `.json` file is 68863 lines or 1827304 characters. I've tried using `pd.read_json`, but I can't get that to work with the way the data is structured.

Comment: Why not just `my_data = json.load(data)`?

Comment: That's not that much data, it should work fine.  +1 for using `load` instead of `loads`

Comment: @itypewithmyhands I get the same problem where it only takes in the data after 67792 lines or 1799045 characters

Comment: maybe first check `print(data.read())`  to see if it read correct file.

Comment: @Ethan you may want to provide a sample file reproduction the issue as it's just impossible to debug this without - but furas suggestion is worth considering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't much in terms of helping you answer your specific question, but based on the discussion in comments, please use something like this code to help you test your JSON I/O:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime

jsonFile = 'D:/test.json'
data = []

print('Generating data...')
for i in range(1000000):
    data.append({
        'star-date': datetime.now().microsecond,
        'captains-log': 'This is entry #{:,}. More later, must go.'.format(i+1)
    })

print('Done!')

print('\nNum rows (in-memory): {:,}'.format(len(data)))
print('First (in-memory): {}'.format(data[0]))
print('Last (in-memory): {}'.format(data[-1]))

print('\nSaving JSON...')
with open(jsonFile, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

print('Done!')
print('Loading JSON...')

jsonData = []
with open(jsonFile) as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)

print('Done!')

print('\nNum rows (from file): {:,}'.format(len(jsonData)))
print('First (from file): {}'.format(jsonData[0]))
print('Last (from file): {}'.format(jsonData[-1]))
```

For me this particular script resulted in a ~85mb JSON file (1 million entries), which took a few seconds to generate and almost as long again to read back. There was no difference in total list count and both the first and last entries seemed to match fine, as expected.

Do you get different results? If not, could there perhaps be an issue with the JSON file you are currently using? How is it generated? Can you try parsing it in one of the many available online JSON formatter/parser tools, to validate?

Cheers